# Can I easily build iPhone apps for my customers without having them signup with the Apple Developer Program?

Tags: iphone, app-store

I do some work for a company and we have an idea.  What we'd like to do is throw in a simple iPhone app if they purchase with our company.  We'd build the app, but the new business would sell it on the Apple Store.  Is this possible without having the business go through all the hoops of signing up for the Apple Developer Program?

To be clear, our company would do 100% of the work. We'd just like to give the app to our customer and be done with it.  We'd rather not see dozens of very similar apps under our company's label.

Comment: You could, of course, offer to help them through the hoops for a reasonable fee.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No.  The submitting company will need to join the Developer Program and be approved and pay the annual fee.

Answer (score 0):

You could (in theory) sell the app through your account, and give them the money.  However the application would NOT be listed under their business name, something no business in their right mind would put up with,